# Timeout Expired using SqlBulkCopy when there are 300Million rows in SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, timeout, sqlbulkcopy

I wasn't having any problems in inserting ~15000 rows in SQL Server database when using SQLBulkCopy in certain conditions where there are 183M existing rows in the database.

But when there were 300M existing rows in the database, i experienced the exception:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Note that there are no constraints or anything.It is just a denormalized table.

```
using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, null))
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_HISTORY_PARMETER_ID,
                    SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_HISTORY_PARMETER_ID);
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP,
                    SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_SOURCE_TIMESTAMP);
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_VALUE_STATUS,
                    SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_VALUE_STATUS);
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_ARCHIVE_STATUS,
                    SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_ARCHIVE_STATUS);
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_INTEGER_VALUE,
                    SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_INTEGER_VALUE);
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_DOUBLE_VALUE,
                    SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_DOUBLE_VALUE);
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_STRING_VALUE,
                    SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_STRING_VALUE);
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_ENUM_NAMEDSET_NAME,
                    SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_ENUM_NAMEDSET_NAME);
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_ENUM_NUMERIC_VALUE,
                    SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_ENUM_NUMERIC_VALUE);
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_ENUM_TEXTUAL_VALUE,
                    SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_FIELD_ENUM_TEXTUAL_VALUE);

                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName =
                    SqlServerDatabaseStrings.SQL_TABLE_HISTORYSAMPLEVALUES;
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(historySampleValuesDataRow);
                sqlBulkCopy.Close();

            }
```

Any ideas on what is happening? BTW, SQL Server Standard is what i'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 properties on your sqlBulkCopy object that can help you

- BulkCopyTimeout: This is the value of the timeout, 30 seconds by default. Set this value to 0 to disable the timeout entirely.
- BatchSize: Instead of inserting 300MM straight into the table, inserts the records at a batched size, maybe 1MM/time to prevent the timeout issue (and ease load a bit)

References:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.bulkcopytimeout(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry there was an error on the statement that i said in my post.It should be inserting ~15000 rows in a database with 183M rows no problem but with 300M rows in database timeout occurred.

Comment: I think the 2 properties can still help you. The easiest thing is just to disable to timeouts, but I would probably then set a batch size of about 1000 as well. There are potentially other things that can be done if you are concerned with performance, but this is a great start.

Comment: Okay thanks Jason, will try to try your suggestion. INitially i was thinking of 5000 as batch size. Is there any guidelines about it?

Comment: I haven't come across any. I usually keep my batches no more than 5k or 10k, but my target tables aren't as large as yours (around 20MM records). 5k should be fine.